SQL Script to return linked dates
I have data that has date from and date to, but they can separate lines i.e.
SELECT
    key1
    ,key2
    ,datefrom
    ,dateto
FROM
(VALUES
('ITEM1','ITEMA',DATETIMEFROMPARTS(2024,01,01,0,0,0,0),DATETIMEFROMPARTS(2024,01,31,0,0,0,0)),
('ITEM1','ITEMA',DATETIMEFROMPARTS(2024,02,01,0,0,0,0),DATETIMEFROMPARTS(2024,05,31,0,0,0,0)),
('ITEM1','ITEMB',DATETIMEFROMPARTS(2024,06,01,0,0,0,0),DATETIMEFROMPARTS(2024,08,31,0,0,0,0)),
('ITEM1','ITEMA',DATETIMEFROMPARTS(2024,09,01,0,0,0,0),DATETIMEFROMPARTS(2099,12,31,0,0,0,0))
) AS x(key1,key2,datefrom,dateto)

In the above what I would like output in the format



key1
key2
datefrom
dateto




ITEM1
ITEMA
2024-01-01
2024-05-31


ITEM1
ITEMB
2024-06-01
2024-08-31


ITEM1
ITEMA
2024-09-01
2099-12-31




You don't explain anything here. You've given us sample data and expected results, great, but you give no details of how you get from A to B.
